# Adding extensionattribute to AD object is not working

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, azure-powershell

Can you please help me with the below code? where am I missing something?
this code is not working.

```
if ($syncO365 -eq "true")
      {
          Write-Host "Sync account to office 365 set to true. Marking Sync On"
          try
              {
                  set-ADUser -Identity $svcAccountName -Add @{extensionAttribute3 = "AADSyncOn"}
              }
          catch
              {
                  Write-Host "Error in aSyncy account to office 365 " -BackgroundColor Red
                  Write-Host $Error[0].Exception -BackgroundColor Red
              }
      }  
      elseif($syncO365 -eq "false")
        {
            Write-Host "Sync account to office 365 set to false. Doing nothing."
        }
```

Comment: _"Not working"_ doesn't give us much information, can you be more specific?

Comment: What is `$syncO365` Looks ike a Boolean, but you are comparing it with strings `"true"` and `"false"`...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Below are few way you can troubleshoot to solve the issue in your code.

1. run the power shell commands in your local and make sure those are working fine.
2. Also as Theo suggested looks like you are comparing Boolean variable with a string. Make sure you check the variables.